# xpath with HTML5 and PHP

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm having a problem to use XPath with HTML5 in PHP.
I'm using this code but it's not working with HTML5 elements, someone can help me?

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$main = $xpath->query("//object");

foreach ($main as $i => $a) 
{
    echo $a->nodeValue;
}
```

I want to take the object element, this one:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="" width="700" height="400">
```

Comment: You might want to explain in more detail in what way "it's not working", i.e. which error you get, or which output exactly you want and which one you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I does perfectly work with **any** element :

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="" width="700" height="400"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
$file = "test.html";
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/object");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        print_r($element);
    }
}
```

even if you omit the `</object>` closing tag (which [you shouldn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object#Examples)).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 does not have to be an well formed xml.

So you cant gaurenteee that an xpath will work.  To navigate the DOM you should use dom methods such as **getElementsByTagName()** or if you have the likes of sizzle or jquery handy use the selector $("object").